# Como criar a lógica de programação de desabilitar um botão depois de uma ação?

Tags: php, javascript-eventos, laravel-5.5

**Contexto:** 

Os **dados de aprovação** somente serão salvos se existir uma emenda salva, 
logo inicialmente o botão de **'salvar'** deve ficar **desabilitado**. Ao salvar a emenda o botão de **'salvar'** é **desabilitado** e os dados da aprovação serão salvos. Mas, como fazer esta lógica?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Método de "cadastroAprovacao" da classe "ProjetoController.php"**

```
 //Cadastra os dados da aba de aprovação
         public function cadastroAprovacao(Request $request)
         {
           $projeto = Projeto::find($request->get('id'));
    /* 
           $emendas = DB::table('emendas_detalhes')
           ->where('projeto_id', $projeto->id)
           ->sum('valor');  */


           $vlInterno =  $this->formatacaoMoeda($request->get('valorInterno'));
           //$vlEmenda =  $this->formatacaoMoeda($emendas);
           //$vlEmenda =  $emendas;
           $vlEmenda = $request->get('valorEmenda');


            $projeto->valor_aprovado_total = 0;
            $projeto->valor_aprovado_total =  $vlInterno + $vlEmenda;
            $projeto->valor_emendas = $vlEmenda; 
            $projeto->valor_interno = $vlInterno;
           // $projeto->valor_contrapartida = $this->formatacaoMoeda($request->get('contrapartida'));
           $projeto->valor_contrapartida =  $request->get('contrapartida') == null ? 0 : $this->formatacaoMoeda($request->get('contrapartida'))  ;
           $projeto->nome_fiscal = $request->get('nomeFiscal'); 
           $projeto->matricula_fiscal = $request->get('matriculaFiscal'); 
           $projeto->dt_pag_autorizado = $request->get('dtAutPagamento'); 
           $projeto->observacao_autorizacao = $request->get('observacaoAprovacao');

           $response =  $projeto->salvarAprovacao($projeto);  

          //Cadastro das ocorrências dos dados da aprovação
           $ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia();
           $ocorrencia->projeto_id = $projeto->id;
           $ocorrencia->usuario_id = Auth::user()->id;
           $ocorrencia->origem = 'A'; //A origem é Automática (A) pois o sistema que registra a ocorrência
           $ocorrencia->tipo = 'I'; //É do tipo Informação (I), pois é feita automática
           $ocorrencia->descricao = "Cadastro dos Dados da Aprovação";
           $ocorrencia->dt_ocorrencia =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
           $ocorrencia->save();


           if($response['success'])
           {
               return redirect()
                         ->route('projeto.edita',$projeto->id) 
                         ->with('success',$response['message']);
           }else
           {
               return redirect()
                         ->back()
                         ->with('error',$response['message']); 

           }   
         }
```

**Modelo: Projeto.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use DB;
use SoftDeletes;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Projeto extends Model
{
    protected $table = "projetos";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    //public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected  $fillable  = ['tipo_processo','processo','dt_protocolo', 'demo','setor_origem_id','proponente_id','nome_projeto',
                               'dt_inicio','dt_fim','dias_intercalados','tipo_projeto_id','modalidade_apoio_id','localidade_id',
                               'valor_solicitado','arquivo_fisico','dt_lancamento','dt_alteracao','dt_alteracao','usu_lancamento_id', 
                               'usu_responsavel_id'];


    public function salvar(array $data)
    {
        $dataInsert['tipo_processo'] = $data['tipoProcesso'];
        $dataInsert['processo'] = $data['numProcesso'];
        $dataInsert['dt_protocolo'] = $data['dtProtocolo'];
        $dataInsert['setor_origem_id'] = $data['setor'];
        $dataInsert['proponente_id'] = $data['proponente'];
        $dataInsert['nome_projeto'] = $data['nomeProjeto'];
        $dataInsert['dt_inicio'] = $data['dtInicio'];
        $dataInsert['dt_fim'] = $data['dtFim'];
        $dataInsert['dias_intercalados'] = $data['diasIntercalados'];
        $dataInsert['tipo_projeto_id'] = $data['tipoProjeto'];
        $dataInsert['modalidade_apoio_id'] = $data['modalidadeApoio'];
        $dataInsert['localidade_id'] = $data['localidade'];
        $cleanPoint = str_replace('.', '', $data['vlSolicitado']);
        $formatedValue = str_replace(',', '.', $cleanPoint);
        $dataInsert['valor_solicitado'] =  $formatedValue;
        $dataInsert['arquivo_fisico'] = $data['arquivo'];
        $dataInsert['dt_lancamento'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $dataInsert['dt_alteracao'] = null;
        $dataInsert['usu_lancamento_id'] = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado
        $dataInsert['usu_responsavel_id'] = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado

        return $this->create($dataInsert);   
    }


   //Este método atualiza os dados do Projeto
   public function alterar(Projeto $projeto) : Array
   {
   DB::beginTransaction();

       $projeto = $this->save();
       if($projeto){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao atualizar o Projeto'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao atualizar o Projeto'
           ]; 
       }
   }


   //Este método remove os dados da Projeto
 public function deletar(Projeto $projeto) : Array
 {
     $projeto = $this->delete();
     if($projeto){
         return[
             'success' => true,
             'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir'
         ];   
     }
     else{
         return[
             'success' => false,
             'message' => 'Falha ao excluir'
         ]; 
     }
 }

    //Este método remove os dados da Notificação
    public function deletarNotificacao(HistoricoNotificacao $notificacao) : Array
    {
        $notificacao = $this->delete();
        if($notificacao){
            return[
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir a notificação'
            ];   
        }
        else{
            return[
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Falha ao excluir a notificação'
            ]; 
        }
    }

        //Este método remove os dados da Errata
        public function deletarErrata(HistoricoErrata $errata) : Array
        {
            $errata = $this->delete();
            if($errata){
                return[
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir a errata'
                ];   
            }
            else{
                return[
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Falha ao excluir a errata'
                ]; 
            }
        }


 public function salvarAprovacao(Projeto $projeto)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $projeto = $this->save();
       if($projeto){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar a Aprovação'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar a Aprovação'
           ]; 
       }
    }

    public function salvarJuridico(Projeto $projeto)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $projeto = $this->save();
       if($projeto){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar o Jurídico'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar o Jurídico'
           ]; 
       }
    }


    public function salvarContratosConvenios(Projeto $projeto)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $projeto = $this->save();
       if($projeto){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar Gestão de Contrato e Convênios'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar Gestão de Contrato e Convênios'
           ]; 
       }
    }

    public function salvarFinanceiro(Projeto $projeto)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $projeto = $this->save();
       if($projeto){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar Financeiro'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar Financeiro'
           ]; 
       }
    }

    //Salvar os dados da notificação
    public function salvarNotificacao(HistoricoNotificacao $notificacao)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $notificacao = $this->save();
       if($notificacao){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar  a Notificação'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar a Notificação'
           ]; 
       }
    }


    //Salvar os dados da  errata
    public function salvarErrata(HistoricoErrata $errata)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

       $errata = $this->save();

       if($errata){
           DB::commit();
           return[
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Sucesso ao Salvar a Errata'
           ];   
       }
       else{
           DB::rollback();
           return[
               'success' => false,
               'message' => 'Falha ao ao Salvar a Errata'
           ]; 
       }
    }


   //Relacionamentos entre a tabela Projeto e localidades_projeto (relacionamento m:m "muitos para muitos")
    public function localidades_projeto()
    {
       return  $this->belongsToMany(Localidade::class, 'localidades_projeto', 'projeto_id',  'localidade_id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Faz uma consulta no banco, e verifica se existe emenda se o retorno for nulo você da um print na palavra disabled dentro do botão.

```
<button <?php echo (!empty($result)) ?: "disabled"; ?> >botão</button>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta.

Comment: Eu fiz a seguinte condicional na página edita.blade. php:                         if ($countEmendas == 0)
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Salvar</button>                            
 else<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Salvar</button>                                                                     endif